# routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]i was trying to understand a mvc application.i saw the following line in **RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I didn't understand the purpose of this line.Why we are ignoring only `.axd`files? I tried in google but didn't get a clear answer. If anyone have idea about mvc please explain.

Let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: [Make Routing Ignore Requests For A File Extension](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx/)

Comment: Thank you Stephen. That was clear. Thank you.